# SQL Server wildcard search on json

Tags: sql, regex, json, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a json stored in SQL `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column something like this:

```
{ "field1":"value1", "field2":"value2" ...}.
```

I want to do wildcard search on any of the fields. A sample query can be:

Give me all rows that contains substring ax in `field2`. The query should return records with fax, axe, etc in `field2`.

Is it possible to do this without writing a SQLCLR function? Attempts using basic regex supported by LIKE was futile.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE json LIKE '%, "field2":"%ax%'
```

Comment: This does not work. If there is a field3 after field2 with halifax, %ax% with match with it. I don't want that.

Comment: that doesn't make sense... post your SQL... my SQL has the field2":" in the LIKE clause, it should only bring back matches for field2

Comment: I modified the answer LIKE clause.  try that, it should work fine.

Comment: Here is a simple example where you can see that it won't work:      create table foo
(
bar nvarchar(max)
)
go

insert foo
values ('{ "field1":"value1", "field2":"fax", "field3":"value3"}')
go
insert foo
values ('{ "field1":"value1", "field2":"boo", "field3":"dax"}')
go

select * from foo where bar like '%, "field2":"%ax%'
go

Comment: As it was mentioned above, `LIKE` search criteria will be useless. The only options for you is to use `CLR` for normal `RegEx` executions or, if you already using `CLR`, you can simply apply the needed `JSON` parsing there. BTW, `RegEx` are not supported by SQL Server (you can add the CLR to support them)

Answer (score 0):

i can do it using the function fnSplitJson2, which can be found at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/JSON/68128/

```
    DECLARE json nvarchar(max)
    SELECT json = 
    '{ "field1":"value1"
     , "field2":"fax"
     , "field3":"axe"
     , "field4":"value4"
     }'

    SELECT name, value
    FROM dbo.fnSplitJson2(json, NULL)
    WHERE value LIKE '%ax%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [JSON Select](https://jsonselect.joshuahealy.net/), as follows:

```
select *
from your_table
where dbo.JsonNVarChar450(your_column, 'field2') like '%ax%'
```

If you're doing this kind of comparison often, you can index the value of `field2` to make it faster, like so:

```
alter table your_table
add field2 as dbo.JsonNVarChar450(your_column, 'field2') persisted

create index IX_your_table_field2 on your_table(field2)
```

DISCLOSURE:  I am the author of JSON Select, and as such I have an interest in you using it :)